# UIGestureRecognizer recognize order problem

Tags: ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a red view and a green view (green view is a subview of redview),and I add a gestureRecognizer to each of them.

[image]

And both grestureRecognizer's `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` return YES.

But when I tap the green view , the redview's gesture delegate method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`  is called first .

Because i think the hit-test view should be the green view . so the green view 's `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` should be the first .

How do the iOS to decide which grestureRecognizer should be recogonized first ?

Post the code and print logs:

```
class GreenView: UIView,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(greenTap))
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
    @objc func greenTap(){
        print("greenTap")
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       print("greenTap shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith")

        return true
    }
    
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
                print("green gestureRecognizerShouldBegin")
        return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}


class RedView: UIView,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(redTap))
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
    @objc func redTap(){
        print("redTap")
    }
    
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
                print("redTap gestureRecognizerShouldBegin")
        return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       print("redTap shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith")

        return true
    }
}
```

and the prints are :

> ```
> green gestureRecognizerShouldBegin
> redTap gestureRecognizerShouldBegin
> green gestureRecognizerShouldBegin
> redTap shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith
> greenTap shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith
> redTap
> greenTap
> ```

**and we can see that the redview(superview) 's shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith and action method is called before the greenview(subview)'s methods**

Comment: The user interaction should be enabled for the both of the view. So when green view  is tapped when it will definitely call green view's method.

Comment: Please post your tried code.

Comment: thanks @Mahendra ,i have added the code and logs , you can see that the redview(superview) 's shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith and action method is called before the greenview(subview)'s methods

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the green view as subview of red view. Just add the green view outside red view above it and center the constraints to red view

Comment: Thanks , but in fact my purpose is to figure out  what 's inside make this weird call order happen？and i actually need the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith called in both red & green view .